# Xpath - Get HTML element if its class contains some text

Tags: html, xpath

Can I get an element if its class contains some text?

Example:

```
<div class="headerbody"></div>   - match (header)
<div class="headerbottom"></div>   - match (header)
<dov class="text"></div>     - not match (header)
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

you could use [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) in your XPath predicate. like this:

```
div[contains(@class, 'header')]
```

Comment: Agreed. Also, if you're worried about case issues, use translate() on your @class first like so: div[contains(translate(@class, 'ABCDEFG..Z', 'abcdefg..z'))]