# Why the query doesn't match the DOM?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

Here is my code:

```
$res = file_get_contents("http://www.lenzor.com/photo/search/index/type/user/%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C//text/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85%D9%87");

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($res);
$xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='user_box']/li");
$result = array();
if (!is_null($links)) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('class');
        $result[] = [$href];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/2cAmHS/1) is the content I'm working on. I mean it's the result of `echo $res`.

---

Ok well, the result of my code is an empty array. So `$links` is empty and that `foreach` won't be executed. Why? Why `//ul[@class='user_box']/li` query doesn't match the DOM ?

Expected result is an array contains the class attribute of `li`s.

Comment: array of `li`'s means `followers_content` ?

Comment: @SahilGulati Yes .. however it's just an example. I want to see a working version of the code.

Comment: `loadHTMLFile` loads __FILE__

Comment: @u_mulder what function should I use to load a HTML content?

Comment: You know, there's a manual. You can read it.

Comment: Second, `@class='user_box'` finds items where class is `user_box`. It __will__ skip items with several classes.

Comment: @u_mulder Ok, I found [`loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadhtml.php). Thank you. And for your second note, can I use `@id='users_search'` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551717/xpath-get-html-element-if-its-class-contains-some-text https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-can-i-match-on-an-attribute-that-contains-a-certain-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Hope this will be helpful. There are few mistakes in your code.

> **1.** You should search like this `'//ul[@class="user_box clearfix"]/li'` because `class="user_box clearfix"` class attribute of that HTML source contains two classes.
>
> **2.** You should use `loadHTML`instead of `loadHTMLFile`.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$res = file_get_contents("http://www.lenzor.com/photo/search/index/type/user/%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C//text/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85%D9%87");

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($res);
$xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="user_box clearfix"]/li');
$result = array();
if (!is_null($links)) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('class');
        $result[] = [$href];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```