# I am confused why this XPath selector does not work

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am learning to use scrapy and playing with XPath selectors, and decided to practice by scraping job titles from craigslist.

Here is the html of a single job link from the craigslist page I am trying to scrape the job titles from:

```
<a href="https://orangecounty.craigslist.org/sof/d/trabuco-canyon-full-stack-net-developer/7134827958.html" data-id="7134827958" class="result-title hdrlnk">Full Stack .NET C# Developer (Mid-Level, Senior) ***LOCAL ONLY***</a>
```

What I wanted to do was retrieve all of the similar a tags with the class result-title, so I used the XPath selector:

```
titles = response.xpath('//a[@class="result-title"/text()]').getall()
```

but the output I receive is an empty list: []

I was able to copy the XPath directly from Chrome's inspector, which ended up working perfectly and gave me a full list of job title names. This selector was:

```
titles = response.xpath('*//div[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/p/a/text()').getall()
```

I can see why this second XPath selector works, but I don't understand why my first attempt did not work. Can someone explain to me why my first XPath selector failed? I have also provided a link to the full html for the craigslist page below if that is helpful/neccessary. I am new to scrapy and want to learn from my mistakes. Thank you!

view-source:https://orangecounty.craigslist.org/search/sof

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xpath - Get HTML element if its class contains some text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551717/xpath-get-html-element-if-its-class-contains-some-text)

Comment: Because your `a` element has more than one class, the `@class="result-title"` test will fail. Instead, you need to check whether the class *contains* result-title.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment in conjunction with the answer below helped me resolve my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
'//a[contains(@class,"result-title ")]/text()'
```

Or:

```
'//a[starts-with(@class,"result-title ")]/text()'
```

I use `contains()` or `starts-with()` because the class of the `a` node is

```
result-title hdrlnk
```

not just

```
result-title
```

---

In your XPath:

```
'//a[@class="result-title"/text()]'
```

even if the class was `result-title`, the syntax is wrong, you should use:

```
'//a[@class="result-title"]/text()'
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense to me now. I had seen in another post that a similar problem had been fixed using the contains() function but I didn't understand why, and didn't realize that it was the solution to my issue as well. I also didn't realize I could use the starts-with() function to identify an element's class. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score -1):

Simply `'//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/text()'`

Needed 2 fixes:

- `/text()` outside of `[]`
- "result-title hdrlnk" not only "result-title" in attribute selection because XPath is XML parsing not CSS; so exact attribute content is needed to match.

Comment: Have you tested ? Not working. Should belongs to a comment

Comment: I had tried this before posting actually but it did not work for me. Thanks anyways though!